# Convert a DistributedMatrix to Scipy sparse or Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, scipy, pyspark

How do I convert some `DistributedMatrix` back into a Numpy array or a Scipy sparse array?

Obviously this is not something I want to do on a big array, but it is helpful for debugging and testing code before running it on actually big data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a naive conversion from `IndexedRowMatrix` to a Scipy sparse matrix:

```py
from scipy.sparse import lil_matrix

def indexedrowmatrix_to_array(x):
    output = lil_matrix((x.numRows(), x.numCols())
    for indexed_row in x.rows.collect():
        output[indexed_row.index] = indexed_row.vector
    return output
```

and for `CoordinateMatrix`:

```py
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

def coordinatematrix_to_array(x):
    output = dok_matrix((x.numRows(), x.numCols())
    for matrix_entry in x.entries.collect():
        output[matrix_entry.i, matrix_entry.j] = matrix_entry.value
    return output
```

You could do something similar for `BlockMatrix` by iterating over the `blocks` attribute and assigning in chunks using the `rowsPerBlock` and `colsPerBlock` attributes.

Comment: `coo` doesn't do indexing.

Comment: @hpaulj you're right, this should be `dok_matrix`. I edited the answer.